# If a Shofar blower must blow twice for two concurrent minyanim, does he need to say the bracha twice?

Tags: halacha, blessing, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

A shul has two minyanim that are about 5 minutes apart from each other. They hire 1 Ba'al T'kiah (shofar blower). He says the bracha at the 1st minyan and blows the first set of 30 blasts. Then he goes to the 2nd minyan. Does he need to repeat the bracha there, or does 1st bracha cover for both minyanim.

The 2nd minyan's congregation had not yet heard any bracha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Mitzva to blow Shofar on Rosh haShana. Accordingly, there is no Bracha on doing so.

This is a Mitzva to *hear* the Shofar being blown, and there is a Bracha said before doing so ("...and commanded us to *hear* the blasts of the Shofar"). Everyone who is fulfilling the Mitzva should say a Bracha. In general, if multiple people are doing a Mitzva contemporaneously, one can say the blessing on behalf of all of them (OC 8:5) and this is commonly done in some communities for publicly performed Mitzvot such as reading the Megillah, hearing the Shofar, counting the Omer, and chanting Hallel.

Additionally, one who has fulfilled his obligation in a Mitzva can say the blessing on behalf of others who have yet to fulfill there Mitzva ("יצא מוציא"). The Rama mentions a custom that the one blowing the Shofar should utilize this option when blowing for others after already fulfilling his own obligation, but most Achronim think this should only be done if the people who have yet to fulfill their obligation cannot say the blessing themselves (for whatever reason). ([OC 585:2 with Mishna Berura](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=111))